# Python Pythonic way to organize/design if statements

Tags: python, design-patterns, if-statement

I'm learning python and I want to make sure I am organizing "if" statements in a correct way. The situation that I keep running a lot into is the following :

```
if x == 0:
    dostuff_A
    if y == 0:
        dostuff_B            
else:
    dostuff_B
```

As you can see I keep repeating "dostuff_B" a lot and have to contantly be changing code twice. I know I could have a function instead "dostuff_B" but my question is regarding the if design. Another workaround that I found is doing the following but then i duplicate the if statement.

```
if x == 0:
    dostuff_A
if x != 0 or y == 0:
    dostuff_B
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE : Removed spaces before colon. Also updated my workaround because didn't make sense. Original version was :

```
if x == 0:
    dostuff_A
if x == 0 and y == 0:
    dostuff_B
```

Comment: The thing here that strikes me as most unpythonic is the space before the `:`

Comment: The code makes no sense.

Comment: The second `if` should be `if x != 0 or y == 0:`

Comment: No, the second if statement is correct. Per the original code, he only wants to do_stuff_B if X == 0 and Y == 0.

Comment: Nope. He also want to do stuff_B when x != 0. So user4815162342 is right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see some correct answers have been posted already but they do not explain how they got to the solution.

One way of simplifying nested `if-else` statements is by using truth tables:

```
x    y    what you call
-----------------------
0    0    A and B
0    1    A
1    0    B
1    1    B
```

From the table above you can see that you only call A when `x == 0`. Let's put that into code:

```
if x == 0:
    somestuff_A
```

From the same table you can see that the only time you don't call B is when `x == 0` and `y == 1`.
Again, let's put that into code:

```
if x != 0 or y == 0:
    somestuff_B
```

or:

```
if not x == 0 or y == 0:
    somestuff_B
```

If you put the two pieces of code together this is what you get:

```
if x == 0:
    somestuff_A
if not x == 0 or y == 0:
    somestuff_B
```

Comment: `not x == 0` always confuses me when I see it. IMO, `x != 0` is preferable

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's more pythonic, but the second style reads more clearly to me (I agree about the space before the colon, and removed it).

```
if x == 0:
    dostuff_A
if x == 0 and y == 0:
    dostuff_B
```

This would hold up for other languages as well.

However, the two examples you have (now that I look at it closer) are not logically equivalent; perhaps you meant this:

```
if x == 0:
    dostuff_A
if x != 0 or y == 0:
    dostuff_B
```

Comment: The issue here is dealing with the case where X != 0, which in the original code block meant destuff_B.

Comment: I like your 2nd example. It addresses the issue I raised above.

Comment: I don’t like how you had to specify `dostuff_B` twice. If that’s a longer statement, or multiple lines, it gets very messy and redundant. In this case a simple `if x != 0 or y == 0` would work.

Comment: Agreed!  I'm now assuming he wanted the logic of his first statement, based on the comments

Comment: @Tom, you copied my answer for the second one =P

Comment: @plalx I also up-voted your answer - not sure the etiquette there!

Comment: @Tom, Me neither hehe, I don't care really ;) Thanks for the vote!

Answer (score 4):

Considering this initial code:

```
if x == 0 :
    dostuff_A
    if y == 0 :
        dostuff_B            
else :
    dostuff_B
```

It can be re-written as:

```
if x == 0:
    dostuff_A
if x != 0 or y == 0:
    dostuff_B
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your `dostuff_B` is actually a larger block of code that should be identical between the branches, and if you change one of the `dostuff_B` you also need to change the other to keep it consistent. In that case there's a very real danger in duplicating the code and you'd be better off being redundant in the `if` statement instead.

As pointed out in the comments your second example isn't identical to the first. It should be:

```
if x == 0:
    dostuff_A
if x != 0 or y == 0:
    dostuff_B
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are correct, your do_stuff should be in two separate functions. Assuming that, I propose the following:

```
if x == 0 and y == 0:
   do_stuff_A()
   do_stuff_B()
elif x == 0:
   do_stuff_A()
else:
    do_stuff_B()
```

In my mind, this makes explicitly clear what is happening in the code as I read it:

- if x and y == 0, then do_stuff_A() and do_stuff_B()
- if x == 0, then do_stuff_A()
- In all other cases, just do_stuff_B()

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of your example, which can be easily rewritten to the code below, I’d say it depends on the situation which makes more sense. In any way, I would try to avoid having to specify `dostuff_A` or `dostuff_B` more than once. So you are allowed to use more complicated conditions there. On the other hand I would keep the two-level if, if the first `dostuff_B` would be related to the previous `dostuff_A` (implying that the second `dostuff_B` would be something else here). If `dostuff_A` and `dostuff_B` are completely unrelated to each other, separating them completely would be preferable.

```
if x == 0:
    dostuff_A

if x != 0 or y == 0:
    dostuff_B
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write a one-time script, it does not matter much which design is more pythonic - if it is understandable it is good. When you start refactoring it to something more usable, you can use the corresponding [refactoring](http://www.martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html).